# Unable to save the chosen item in the first spot of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I cant save my input in my array, so when i put all the answers in, and i want to see what i have in my array, all the spots are empty. This is whats happening since i put the if-statement there. If i remove the if-statement, the input will be saved in my array but it will miss the first input, so i will have 23 out of 24 answers.

I've tried to write an else-statement as well, but same problem with the one missing, same if i delete the whole if-statement.

```
    {


        if (numberOfBottles < 24)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Write what sodas u want in the crate:"); // Skriver ut text och ber användaren skriva drycken. 

            int soda_input = 0;

            string chosenSoda = "";
            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("1: Coca-cola"); // skriver ut alternativen för flaska
                Console.WriteLine("2: Fanta");
                Console.WriteLine("3: Pepsi");
                Console.WriteLine("4: Beer");
                Console.WriteLine("5: Redbull");
                Console.WriteLine("6: Cider");
                Console.WriteLine("7: Water");


                try
                {
                    soda_input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Just numbers, my friend");
                    continue;
                }

                if (chosenSoda == null)**
                {
                    crate[numberOfBottles] = chosenSoda; // lagrar svaren i min vektor
                } THIS IS THE IF-STATEMENT THAT IS MESSING EVERYTHING UP

                numberOfBottles++;  // för varje svar jag skriver så ökar det med 1 i vektorn hela vägen till 24

                switch (soda_input) // Skapar en meny, som skriver ut vilken dryck användaren väljer tills backen blir full.
                {

                    case 1:
                        chosenSoda = "Coca-Cola";
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Coca-Cola");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        chosenSoda = "Fanta";
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Fanta");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        chosenSoda = "Pepsi";
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Pepsi");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        chosenSoda = "Öl";
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Öl");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        chosenSoda = "Redbull";
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Redbull");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        chosenSoda = "Cider";
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Cider");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        chosenSoda = "Vatten";
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Vatten");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;


                    default: // om man skriver siffror ovanför 1-7 så skrivs detta ut.
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Siffor mellan 1-7 min vän");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        break;
                }

            } while (numberOfBottles != 24);

        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("The crate is full, choose some of the alteratives to check the crate:");
        Console.WriteLine("");


    }
```

EDIT: "Du valde, means U chose.. in swedish.

Comment: You have put check of null, code will not got insider if the chosedSoda is not null `if (chosenSoda == null)**
                {
                    crate[numberOfBottles] = chosenSoda; // lagrar svaren i min vektor
                } ` I think you wan to put !=

Comment: You probably want to assign the value to the array AFTER you have decided what has been chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the array value before you have chosen anything.

Additionally, you probably want to keep them in the loop and not assign a value if the input is invalid.

To do this you move the if to after the switch, but before the while statement.  By checking for not equal (!=) to null (which I don't think it will ever be) and also checking for not equal to "", you are forcing them to stay on the current bottle and keep inputting until they make a valid selection.

Try this:

```
do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("1: Coca-cola"); // skriver ut alternativen för flaska
            Console.WriteLine("2: Fanta");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Pepsi");
            Console.WriteLine("4: Beer");
            Console.WriteLine("5: Redbull");
            Console.WriteLine("6: Cider");
            Console.WriteLine("7: Water");


            try
            {
                soda_input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Just numbers, my friend");
                continue;
            }

            switch (soda_input) // Skapar en meny, som skriver ut vilken dryck användaren väljer tills backen blir full.
            {

                case 1:
                    chosenSoda = "Coca-Cola";
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Coca-Cola");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    chosenSoda = "Fanta";
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Fanta");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    chosenSoda = "Pepsi";
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Pepsi");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    chosenSoda = "Öl";
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Öl");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    chosenSoda = "Redbull";
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Redbull");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    chosenSoda = "Cider";
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Cider");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;

                case 7:
                    chosenSoda = "Vatten";
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Vatten");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;


                default: // om man skriver siffror ovanför 1-7 så skrivs detta ut.
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Siffor mellan 1-7 min vän");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                    break;
            }

 if (chosenSoda != null && chosenSoda != "")
            {
                crate[numberOfBottles] = chosenSoda; // lagrar svaren i min vektor
            numberOfBottles++;
            }

        } while (numberOfBottles != 24);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. God bless you, im new to this as u can see